# Is using sequence the right approach to give monadic arguments to a function of arity greater than 1?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, ramda.js, fantasyland

See the following code snippet:

```
const
  fun1 = () => Either.of(1),
  fun2 = () => Either.of(2),
  fun3 = () => Either.of(3),
  fun4 = curry((x, y, z) => Either.of(x + y + z)),
  fun5 = x => Either.of(x + 1),
  fun6 = () => pipeK(
    () => sequence(Either.of, [fun1(), fun2(), fun3()]),
    apply(fun4),
    fun5
  )(),

result = fun6() // returns 7
```

`fun4` requires 3 arguments and I'd like to give them only if all of them are *right* arguments. That is, `sequence` will apply each monadic value so I'll get them as a single *right* containg the raw `fun1`, `fun2`, `fun3` return values.

Is this the recommended  approach?

<sup>[Click here for run the whole code snippet](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%0A%20%20fun1%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20Either.of%281%29%2C%0A%20%20fun2%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20Either.of%282%29%2C%0A%20%20fun3%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20Either.of%283%29%2C%0A%20%20fun4%20%3D%20curry%28%28x%2C%20y%2C%20z%29%20%3D%3E%20Either.of%28x%20%2B%20y%20%2B%20z%29%29%2C%0A%20%20fun5%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%20Either.of%28x%20%2B%201%29%2C%0A%20%20fun6%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20pipeK%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20sequence%28Either.of%2C%20%5Bfun1%28%29%2C%20fun2%28%29%2C%20fun3%28%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20apply%28fun4%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fun5%0A%20%20%29%28%29%0A%0Afun6%28%29%20%2F%2F%20returns%207)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would not use `sequence` with an array and `apply`. I think the more idiomatic approach is to use [`ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap):

```
const fun6 = () => chain(fun5, unnest(ap(ap(ap(Either.of(fun4), fun1()), fun2()), fun3())));
// or
const fun6 = () => chain(fun5, unnest(ap(ap(map(fun4, fun1()), fun2()), fun3())));
// or
const fun6 = () => Either.of(fun4).ap(fun1()).ap(fun2()).ap(fun3()).chain(identity).chain(fun5);
```

The equivalent in Haskell would be `fun5 =<< join (fun4 <$> fun1 <*> fun2 <*> fun3)`. The [`unnest`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#unnest) is needed when `fun4` returns an Either, which might not be necessary.

Comment: Hey, Bergi. First of all, thank you for your answer. The equivalent in Haskell is afforable, but the JavaScript one is harder to read, isn't it? Would you go with this solution when `sequence` one has by far less noise?

Comment: In fact, I can even wrap ramda's `sequence` to use *rest params* and the same call would look less noisy: `sequence(Either.of, fun1(), fun2(), fun3())`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, you can do something like that, but variadic functions don't go well with type systems. Better call it [`liftA3` like Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA3) :-) To further improve readability, drop the Unit argument from your "functions" and just make them constant values.

Comment: Really it's hard to make a choice. The optimal solution is less readable than a suboptimal one... I understand that using `ap` and `chain` I'm avoiding unnecessary iterations.

Comment: Uhm, when you suggested me Haskell's `liftA3` I understand that I can generalize your approach into a `liftA3` the JS/ramda way so I'll be able to call `liftA3(fun5, fun1, fun2, fun3)`, right?

Comment: BTW I've tried your code and it has some problem: it doesn't map the result to `fun5`. It gives the `Either.right` without mapping it to `fun5`.

Comment: Yes, that `liftA3` is what I meant.

Comment: Regarding `fun5`, doesn't `chain` work on eithers? Is the result of `liftA3` the expected one? I think `chain` is better than `pipeK` when there's only a single function to be flat-mapped over a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157295/discussion-between-matias-fidemraizer-and-bergi).

Comment: There's still an issue. You should use some other identifier for `join` since ramda already has a `join` function (I've already done in my code, but it's just for the sake of correctness of your answer).

Comment: Also, what about providing the dotted version too? `liftA3 = (fun4, fun1, fun2, fun3) => Either.of(fun4).ap(fun1()).ap(fun2()).ap(fun3()).chain(identity)` and `fun6 = () => liftA3(fun4, fun1, fun2, fun3).chain(fun5)`

Comment: Ah, they called it `unnest`.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort. In fact, both first and second approaches are definitively the way to go as they can work with any applicative, while the third one is tied to `Either`.

Comment: Uhm I can't edit my previous comment. But I wanted to say that #2 approach is the best because it can handle any applicative.

Comment: ...any applicative and functor ;D